# Irregular intervals - where to draw a line?

Tags: algorithm, date, charts, statistics, intervals

I have a line chart ( x represents date, y represents amount of car rentals on that date) that needs to be connected at all times, since the values are all valid - there is always at least one car rental per that date. The only time that the line shouldn't be connected, but should make a gap between two valid values/points is when the two successive dates are too wide apart. I have to figure out the best alghorithm for what this 'two wide apart' means and, based on these dates (or something), set a parameter.I don't know all the possible combinations of dates, but I think they can be anything:

- 2010 2011 2013 2018 2019
  or
- 1990 2001 2002 2012 2015
  or
- possibly anything else

Is there any standard way to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: diif / median(diff) > k

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to characterize what it means to be *too wide apart*. One solution is to build a histogram (i.e. a probability density function) of the date differences of the x coordinates of the data points, and then to consider as *too wide*, those differences that are in, say the top 33% (or whatever other proportion you wish).

For example, suppose the x coordinates are the years:

```
1990 1995 2001 2002 2003 2010 2011 2012 2013 2017 2019
```

Let say we calculate date differences in years (we could choose any other duration unit). We calculate the differences between the values above and build the histogram below.

```
Counts: 5 1 0 1 1 1 1
Diff.:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Now, if we choose to keep disconnected differences in the top 33%, from the histogram, this means that differences greater than or equal to 5 years would be disconnected.

Comment: @Mandy - Did that answer your question?